# ActionHero.js Framework with Oracle database persistence

Tags: node.js, oracle, api, rest, actionhero

I am quite new working with nodejs, I need to make a REST API that can work with websocket. I was searching for a framework that I could work with, I found actionhero.js, I think that can fit my needs.

But I see a little problem with this framework, that I can't find information about how can I make it work with oracle database, I will be really  grateful if any of you can give me a light on how can I make it work this framework with a Oracle Database, or suggest me a framework based on REST API that can fit my needs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actionhero is, as you point out, a REST API framework.  It doesn't include any database drivers (other than for redis, which it uses for cluster communication).  You can easily ad support for any database you like in an [initializer](http://www.actionherojs.com/docs/#initializers).

There are also plugins which add database support.  For example, the [ah-sequelize-plugin](https://github.com/evantahler/ah-sequelize-plugin/) adds support for the [Sequelize ORM](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize), probably the most popular node.js ORM.  Sequelize doesn't support the Oracle DB out of the box (very few things do), but there exist drivers you can use: https://github.com/adeo-proxideco/sequelize-oracle

Comment: Thank you Evan for you help!